# Forzar "Sitio inseguro" level 3 [para propósitos de demostración]

Tags: html, script, google-chrome, chrome

Bien, se entiende que hay 3 niveles de seguridad en las versiones +18 de Google Chrome.

[image: Niveles de seguridad en Google Chrome Versión +18]

Al parecer si no tienes un certificado SSL estarías en el nivel 2, simplemente muestra un mensaje color gris que te indica que no debes introducir información confidencial en el sitio, pero no es el mensaje que busco.

Tengo una disertación de seguridad en la universidad y necesito mostrar una página con el nivel 3 de seguridad, donde la barra muestra el texto de No seguro con color rojo.

He leído que esto pasa cuando tienes publicidad o script maliciosos.

La demostración la estoy montando en un subdominio (la idea es mostrar los 3 niveles entrando a 3 subdominios diferentes), a este subdominio lo he forzado a usar sólo HTTP gracias .htaccess para que sea lo más inseguro posible, pero sólo he logrado dejar la barra en color gris.

¿Alguna idea para hacer el subdominio lo más inseguro posible? La idea es mostrar un mensaje de "Sitio web fraudulento" o muy inseguro.

Comment: puedes hacerlo cargano javascript de un sitio http externo u imagenes o replicando una web famosa o agregando sus meta tag para que chorme los lea y los cataloge como pishing!

Comment: Hola @Bryro! Voy a probar, pero la idea no es replicar otro sitio, aún así voy a probar a cargar javascript http externo, si tienes algún otro tip te lo agradecería!

Comment: otra opción es instalando un Certificado SSL no valido(trucho).

Comment: puedes denunciarla también: https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?hl=es-419 a ver si sale.

Comment: @zerocool y si logro denunciarlo esto afecta al dominio o sólo al subdominio? Me parece una mala idea denunciarme a mi mismo para motivos demostrativos.

Comment: solo una idea más... en éste caso podrías usar un hosting/dominio gratis.

Comment: @FranIslas Hola Fran, he posteado en varios foros y al parecer la alternativa más viable es la que me dices tu, instalar un certificado auto firmado con otro dominio o simplemente que esté vencido. Lo que pasa es que es un servidor local (no tiene cPanel) por lo que no entiendo muy bien si debo dejarlo en pki-validation como lo hago con los cPanel o hay que hacer algo más. Saludos.